# Lucene: facet range depends on the returned results

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, facet

I have a working search set up where I give the facet range, and get the correct results back.
The problem is that for prices facet, I need to be depending on the returned result, so I can't know the ranges beforehand.

Example 1: the search found 4 products with the following prices: 20, 30, 40, 55. So I expect the facets be something like this:

```
0 - 20 (1)
21 - 40 (2)
41 - 60 (1)
```

Example 2: the search found 2 products with the following prices: 200, 400, So I expect the facets be something like this:

```
100 - 200 (1)
300 - 400 (1)
```

Is there somewhere in Lucene where I can specify that I want the ranges be based on a field from the search results?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After many searching I did not find a way to do it out of the box.
The way to do it, is to extend `DrillSideways`, and at the beginning of the `BuildFacetsResult` method, we extract the field with the necessary value. Something like this:

```cs
public class DrillSidewaysHelper : DrillSideways
{
    private TopFieldCollector _localCollector;
    private List<decimal> _prices;
    protected override LuceneFacets BuildFacetsResult(FacetsCollector drillDownCollector, FacetsCollector[] drillSidewaysCollectors,
            string[] drillSidewaysFacets)
    {
       ExtractResults(); //here we extract the methods from the _localCollector and populate _prices
        ....here we can generate the facets range based on the _prices

    }

    public FacetResultSet<T> OurSearch(DrillDownQuery drillDownQuery, Sort sort)
    {
        int limit = m_searcher.IndexReader.MaxDoc;

        _localCollector = TopFieldCollector.Create(sort, limit, null, true, true, false, true);
        var drillSidewaysResult = Search(drillDownQuery, _localCollector);

        var facets = ExtractFacets(drillSidewaysResult.Facets);

        return new FacetResultSet<T>(_results, (uint) _localCollector.TotalHits, facets);
    }
}
```

and usage:

```cs
var drillSideways = new DrillSidewaysHelper(searcher, facetsConfig, taxonomyReader);

return drillSideways.OurSearch(drillDownQuery, sort);
```